# Java string variable issue

Tags: java

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int z = 5 + 2;
        string na = "Sarah";
        System.out.println("This is SO Java! " + na);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't run right...

I'm aware of this being an extremely stupid question, but I get:

> ```
> /MyClass.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
> na = "Sarah";
> ^
>   symbol:   variable na
>   location: class MyClass
> /MyClass.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
> System.out.println("This is SO Java! " + na);
>                                           ^
>   symbol:   variable na
>   location: class MyClass
> 2 errors
> ```

Comment: It's `String` not `string`

Comment: Um okay, thats right, it was a stupid question xD But why is it capital? is there any historical reason for it or is it just dat way

Comment: It's a Java code convention that classes start with a capital letter. (The *primitive types* `int`, `boolean`, etc. are not *classes*)

Comment: Wait so strings are classes?

Comment: And not variables? @SimonAndréForsberg

Comment: `String` is a class, yes. Variable **names** should start with a lowercase letter. (Such as `na` and `z` in your code above)

Comment: why is it a class? I thought a class was a function or something like it

Comment: @dfdf First: [Java String is Special](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html), second: [The Official Oracle's Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

String has a capital S not string. All class names in Java start with a capital letter unlike primitive types which start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Um okay, thats right, it was a stupid question xD But why is it capital? is there any historical reason for it or is it just dat way

Comment: It's because the type name is String. It's case sensitive. It wouldn't work if you wrote "Int z=5+2;" or "INT z=5+2;" either. You can declare classes with lower-case names at the beginning, but it's advised against (read more on the subject here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 1):

Declaration for the variable 'na' is incorrect. 
It should be:

```
String na="Sarah";
```